# Is there a better way to show $a^3 -4ab +8c = 0$ for this polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

$x^3 +ax^2 +bx +c = 0 $ has roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ and  $\gamma$, where $\gamma=\alpha+\beta $. Show that $a^3 -4ab +8c = 0$ . I have done it through relations of roots ($\alpha$ + $\beta$ + $\gamma$ = $\frac{-b}{a} = -a$ and etc.) and substituing $\gamma$ into every single equation, then substituing them into what is required to be shown (sub in $ a, b$ and $c$). Is there a faster method to show this, maybe a smarter substitution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** you  dont need to sub in every equation

$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-a$$
$$\gamma=-a/2$$

As this is a root ....substituiting in cubic $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ we have $$a^3-4ab+8c=0$$

Comment: Nice! +1. But right using of Viète  also gives  a short  solution.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah someone also suggested Vietas formulas which I will look into. @Albus Dumbledore, how did you know to make $\gamma$ the subject though? I thought of that but I was nerved by the fact that $\frac{-a}{2}$ was a fraction, and negative.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yours is also nice it did not strike  me

Comment: @user71207 because i have done many similar problems for JEE(a competitive exam in india)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe so:
$$a^3-4ab+8c=-8(\alpha+\beta)^3-4(-2\alpha-2\beta)\cdot(\alpha\beta+(\alpha+\beta)^2)-8\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)=0.$$